# How can I make a button with an image work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make a button, using my own image. But when I tried it it doesn't work. What I wanted the button to do is to open the URL. I'm not sure what went wrong despite trying other methods.

Code is written in SwiftUI. Also, there are no errors shown in my code. Any leads, please.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Text("Whoami?")
                .font(.system(size: 35.0, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: -110, y: -360)
            
            //name
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.black]), startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .trailing)
                .mask(Text("text").font(Font.system(size: 30)).fontWeight(.semibold))
                .frame(width: 370)
                .offset(x: 75, y: -280)
            //bio
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.black]), startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .trailing)
                .mask(Text("text").font(Font.system(size: 25)).fontWeight(.semibold))
                .frame(width: 350)
                .offset(x: -20, y: -100)
            //image
            Image("Keb")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 125, height: 125)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5))
                .offset(x: -120, y: -250)
            
            //github
            
            Button(action:  {
                openURL(URL(string: "https://github.com/")!)
                print("tapped")
            }) {
                Image("git")
                    .resizable()
                    .offset(x: 10, y: -230)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    
            }
            
            //ig
            Button(action: {
                openURL(URL(string: "https://instagram.com/")!)
                print("tapped")
            }) {
                Image("ig2")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .offset(x: 70, y: -225)
   
            }
 
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, read by screen readers, etc.  Are you sure you have an image named "git" in your image assets?

Comment: Also, please add error or issues.

Comment: Updated. There is no errors in my code. The image is shown but the button is not working.

Comment: what not work? Is the image not display? URL not working?

Comment: The `offset` makes me wonder if you're actually hitting the `Button`. What happens if you remove the offset?

Comment: I added the offset because I wanted to place it at a specific position. It does not affect the code I think?

Comment: Okay, but what happens if you *remove* it for debugging purposes? Does the button then "work"?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: In that case, please include enough code for a [mre] (ie, copy-and-pastable into Xcode in a blank SwiftUI project) so that this can be debugged.

Comment: Please add reproducible code or ss of the current screen to avoid assumptions. Or try to set zIndex(1) for button

Comment: I have added my full code. No errors at all, just the button not working.

Answer (score 1):

Set offset and frame out side button

```
Button(action:  {
    openURL(URL(string: "https://github.com/")!)
    print("tapped")
}) {
    Image("git")
        .resizable()
}
.offset(x: 10, y: -230) // <- Here
.frame(width: 50, height: 50) // <- Here
```

The issue is you are setting frame and offset to image view which is inside the button but your button position is not changing it still has an original frame. You can check by giving background color to the button.

Comment: Thank you really much! I've been figuring out why it doesn't work...And how it works! Thank you

Comment: @Conqueriings glad to help you. you can accept the answer if it helped you.